# What are the fees for using the Firebase Auth REST API as an alternative to the Firebase Authentication SDK?

Tags: firebase-authentication

We are aware that there is a fee for using Firebase Authentication if you exceed the free limit for the Blaze plan as described in the following URL.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth#pay_as_you_go_blaze

Are there any other fees for using Firebase Auth REST API other than the fee for exceeding the free allowance in the Blaze plan?

If I use the Firebase Auth REST API, will I have to pay for read, write, delete, etc. as described in the following URL since I will be using the Cloud Firestore?
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#select-region

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are there any other fees for using Firebase Auth REST API other than the fee for exceeding the free allowance in the Blaze plan?

No, the costs are same whether you use Firebase SDKs (that use REST APIs under the hood) or the REST API directly.

> will I have to pay for read, write, delete, etc. as described in the following URL since I will be using the Cloud Firestore?

Firestore is totally different product from authentication and has separate billing.

You can check pricing of all the Firebase products [here](https://firebase.google.com/pricing)